# Skip validations in importing rails_admin in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

How can i skip the validation of a field in model if I'am importing it in rails_admin_import? like:

```
Class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :dog_quantity
has_many :dog_price
validates_presence_of :dog_quantity, :dog_price, :on => :import
end
```

is there anyway to do it? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a caveat.   I don't use rails_admin or the rails_admin_import gem.  However, according to the documentation at https://github.com/stephskardal/rails_admin_import#import-hooks, you can:

> Define instance methods on your models to be hooked into the import
>   process, if special/additional processing is required on the data:

Like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def before_import_save(record)
    # Your custom special sauce
  end

  def after_import_save(record)
    # Your custom special sauce
  end
end
```

Knowing that, you could set a temporary flag on the model/record called something like `is_importing` inside of the `#before_import_save` hook  and conditionally validate based on its value.  For example:

```
Class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dog_quantity
  has_many :dog_price
  validates :dog_quantity, presence: true, unless: :is_importing
  validates :dog_price, presence: true, unless: :is_importing

  attr_accessor :is_importing

  def before_import_save(record)
    record.is_importing = true         
  end
end
```

A couple of things to note here.   First, I split the validations out into two statements.   Secondly, I'm using the newer-style validation syntax which I think became available in Rails 4.  Conventionally, this style is preferred.  If you're using Rails versions < 4, then go back to using `validates_presence_of`, and it should still work.     Thirdly, `is_importing` will be nil if `before_import_save` is never called, and since evaluates to falsey, the validation will be fired as expected during normal operation of the application (ie:  not importing).

As I said, I didn't test any of this and I'm more or less going off the top of my head, so there may be errors.   Nonetheless, my sense is that utilizing import hooks to solve the problem is what you're going to want.

Comment: Thanks, tried to do it but still got error "Undefined is_importing....". Thank you for giving me an idea.

Comment: did you remember to add the attr_accessor to your Dog model? @IsmaelEri

Comment: even though i put the accessor it still gives me an error "Error during import: undefined method `is_importing=' for #<Hash:0x007fdda474f098> (/var/www/html/test/alet-api/app/models/product.rb:21:in `before_import_save')".

Comment: I tried to change the `record.is_importing` to  `is_importing = true` it doesn't give me an error but the validations still works.

Comment: I see.   So the `record` argument is referencing a hash, and it would appear that the virtual attribute value is effectively being cleared before validations run.   As an experiment, maybe try this.   Add an `is_importing` field to the dogs table, and inside the before hook, set the value to true using: `self.is_importing = true'.  In the after hook, set that flag back to false.    I'd probably make that flag default to false in your migration.    Adding a field to the table just to support conditional validation is kinda janky, but maybe try it and see what happens?

Comment: Thanks for the idea but that will be my last option. Adding a field in the table would be a quite mess if that field will just support the conditional validation.

Comment: I don't blame you haha.   I felt a little gross even suggesting it.

Comment: Thanks by the way, I'll post my solution if ever. Haha

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try asking the question on the RailsAdmin [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rails_admin).

You might also want to read "[Get Rid of Your Admin Gem](http://rubyjunky.com/get-rid-of-your-admin-gem.html)".

And, have you studied the Active Record Validations Guide section on [conditional validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation) carefully?

Answer (score 0):

So my solution was to fork the *rails_admin_import* and inside the *`importer.rb`* file i changed the

```
if object.save
```

into

```
if object.save(:validate => false)
```